# How to shared state data with redux and react-hooks

Tags: react-native, react-redux, react-hooks

im trying to use react hooks to load my state and redux to store state data. But it is a little difficult to find the right way to do this, if it is possible. Can someone help me?

Example:

1 - screen A. Title = myTitleScreenA.

2 - screen B. changeTitle(myTitleScreenB).

3 - screen B. dispatch new title to store.

4 - screen B. navigation go back (B -> A).

5- screen A. loads new title myTitleScreenB.

getting data from already stored state, from screen A:

```
const diaryData = useSelector(({diaryState}) => diaryState.data);
const diaryIndex = useSelector(({diaryState}) => diaryState.index);


const [diary, setDiary] = useState(diaryData[diaryIndex]);

useEffect(() => {
    console.log('im here');
    setLoad(true);
    setDiary(diaryData[diaryIndex]);
    setLoad(false);
  });
```

at screen B, changing the state and dispatching info:

```
 diary.growDimens = growDimens;
 diary.lightingType = lightingType;
 diary.lumens = lumens;

 diaryData[diaryIndex] = diary;
 dispatch(diaryFetchSuccess(diaryData));
```

I expected that when performing the dispatch, the diary state of screen a would be modified. But it's not.

Comment: I found a way, but i think that is wrong way. Im sending navigation param onGoBack from screen a to b. And after update diary model -> execute onGoBack.